# CSS Animation - Parser Error

Tags: html, css, parsing

I am getting parser error when I try to use CSS animations.

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: "-" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.

```
<html>
<head>
.spin {
        -webkit-animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
        -o-animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
        animation: spin .2s infinite linear;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 58%;
        transform-origin: 50% 58%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 58%; /* IE 9 */
    }

    @-moz-keyframes spin {
        from {
            -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }

        to {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }



</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="text-center">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star spin"></span>
</h1>

<h3 class="text-center">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star spin"></span>
</h3>

<h6 class="text-center">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send spin"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star spin"></span>
</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: looks like you missed a `<style>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Add `<style type="text/css">` just below the head tag and above your CSS code.  It looks like you have the closing tag at the bottom already.